# How to connect sink, dishwasher and washing machine with single water supply?

Tags: water, washing-machine, dishwasher, kitchen-sink

I am mounting kitchen and in my new apartment I found this kind of water supply tap. I am not sure how I can connect it with all three sink, dishwasher and washing machine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :-)

[image]

Comment: How do these two valves work? Is the small valve on top independent of the larger center one? Or does the larger valve in the center shut off the water to both?

Comment: Where are you? This is the cold water supply right? Do you have a central hot water supply or do you use electric point of use hot water heaters for the kitchen sink, dishwasher, clothes washer,  and bathroom lavatory and shower? Or do you just have cold water coming out everywhere except maybe the shower (which may have an electric heater in the shower head).

Comment: We could tell you exactly how to adapt it for your needs if only we knew (or could see) the connector sizes for the sink. For the dishwasher you likely need to adapt to 3/8" compression thread; for the washing machine you likely need garden-hose thread, which is the size of both outlets of that wye adapter.

Comment: Weirdly I can not comment on my post, because I don't have 50 reputation :-P. How I would suppose to reply you guys? I live in Germany and this is the only water supply valve in my kitchen. I am totally ignorant in this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I find it's best to assume the last guy had the same problem you are now having, and what you see is his solution.

It looks like it was factory made as a double tap, with an outlet on top and bottom, and the top one was never used (or his fitting did not need tape).  From the bottom tap, the last guy put a splitter on it, to get 2 outlets from the one tap (while strangly not using the upper tap at all).

Behold 3 taps for you.

I don't think this is a tub/shower diverter, the valve angle is wrong, and that would be rather strange since there's no hot/cold mixer and it would be out-of-place in this location.

Comment: Not that strange that the top was unused - the fitting is a different diameter. It looks smaller than what a standard appliance hose would attach to.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same problem. I just want to hook my portable washing machine to the same tap that the K. sink is tapped off of. (Using a splitter). I believe I need a 3/4in (AKA, garden hose) TO> 1/4in compression adapter/splitter. Two. One for hot, one for cold. I can't find any such adapter anywhere on the planet@*T%$$??!!?ER*&..... Please, Bitte Schonn, Por Favor, Ku da sa ii !!  Does anybody know where to find such adapters???
Pauly H.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/143015)

Comment: Please ask this as a new question instead of as an answer to a question, but note that "Shopping assistance, product recommendations, or brand specific advice." are [off-topic for this site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Excellent point, @AndrewMorton! "Where do I find X device" will be closed, as well. The answer to this one is probably going to be, "buy a collection of adapters to make it work, 'cause they don't build a one-piece solution for your unique need".